# how to remove <hr> tag for last last item in polymer dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

here is my code

```
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
   <a href="{{data.path}}">
      <button id="myButton" class="dropbtn">{{data.name}}</button>
   </a>
   <paper-listbox id="menuListBox" class="dropdown-content" slot="dropdown-
              content" selected="1">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data.submenu}}">
          <paper-item id="subMenu">
             <template is="dom-if" if="{{_isSubMenu(item.submenu.length)}}">
                <geo-dropdownmenu class="submenu" data={{item}} animation-
                      direction="right" menu="submenu"></geo-dropdownmenu>
             </template>
             <template is="dom-if" if="{{!_isSubMenu(item.submenu.length)}}">
               <a href="{{item.path}}" id="paperItemType"> {{item.name}} </a>
             </template>
             </paper-item>
                   <hr>
          </template>
   </paper-listbox>

</div>
```

here am creating a dropdown menu using paper-listbox and paper item ,
am using **dom-repeat** for the paper item and in that am checking whether the paper item is submenu or not using **dom-if** (_isSubMenu() is a function to check whether the paper-item is submenu or not) , am using

---

tag to seperate the paper-items in the listbox, but i don't want hr tag after last paper-item in the listbox

Comment: check for the last index and don't add it. last index is your array length-1

Comment: css: `paper-listbox hr:last-child { display: none; }`

Comment: i tried already paper-listbox hr:last-child { display: none; }  css style but it is not working  @dandavis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) in your Polymer template's style to target the last `<hr>`:

```
hr:last-of-type { display: none; }
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OxKoKZ?editors=1010)